# Retry failed readline of stdout with different encoding

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, stdout, python-unicode

Using Python, I am running a jmeter process, using the following code:

```
with subprocess.Popen(jmeterscript, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, encoding="utf-8", shell=True) as process:
    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline().strip()
        if line == '':
            break
        print(line)
        retval += line
```

But my script threw an error at the readline call:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 555: invalid continuation byte
```

because it detected a latin-1 character (0xE9), which is not compatible with the utf-8 encoding.

I'd like to catch this Exception and try printing out that stdout line with a different encoding (or bytes only), to help me identify the line that broke. But because it's in the middle of a stdout utf-8 process, I can't think of how to do that.

Comment: If this is on Windows, as I assume, then you probably want to specify `encoding='cp1252'` when you launch the process.

Comment: Thanks, but the script has utf-8 characters and expects them. When it runs into the Latin-1 character I expect it to throw an error, and I want to catch the Exception.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way to do this, which is to set encoding to None and decode each line into a string. There is more flexibility over that, and I can print out the offending line as bytes:

```
    with subprocess.Popen(strtorun, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, encoding=None, shell=True) as process:
        while True:
            line = process.stdout.readline().strip()
            try:
                line = line.decode("utf-8")
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                print("\n*Output has invalid (non utf-8) characters! Invalid output: {}\n".format(line))
                raise
            if line == '':
                break
            print(line)
            retval += line
```